# How to make rectangular and round corner panel like facebook

Tags: android, mobile, view

I am very new in android and want to make a rectangular and round corner pan/view  in with a grey background without using facebook SDK. such pan is also used in many other mobile apps like linkedin.

Not able to post snapshot due to no reputation :(

thanks in advance.

Ajay

Comment: post a link to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create shape.xml in drawable folder

like
shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <stroke android:width="2dp"
     android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
  <gradient 
    android:angle="225"
    android:startColor="#DD2ECCFA"
    android:endColor="#DD000000"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

and in myactivity.xml

you can use:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Shap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Shape"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am now able to make the shape as wanted using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We can do that using background image

Code example :

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/d10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d10"
        android:background="@drawable/background_withoutgrid" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/canvas_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@null" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/canvosImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

It viewed as below

[image]

Comment: Dear Salem, I have tried this approach but unable to get the shape appearing above. Hope the image is not with me.